Extract number between XML tags and adding some numbers as single text line
I am trying to extract number between the two tags. Here its <startSample>somenumber</startSample> and <pitch>number with dot</pitch> then adding 10000 and 10200
sample text :
<audGrainData>
  <startSample>253</startSample>
  <pitch>14.1668348</pitch>
</audGrainData>
<audGrainData>
  <startSample>2390</startSample>
  <pitch>14.1668348</pitch>
</audGrainData>
<audGrainData>
  <startSample>4521</startSample>
  <pitch>14.1668348</pitch>
</audGrainData>
<audGrainData>
  <startSample>6475</startSample>
  <pitch>14.1668348</pitch>
</audGrainData>
<audGrainData>
  <startSample>8547</startSample>
  <pitch>14.2084284</pitch>
</audGrainData>

and I want it to be like this:
  253 14.1668348 10000 10200
  2390 14.1668348 10000 10200
  4521 14.1668348 10000 10200
  6475 14.1668348 10000 10200
  8547 14.2084284 10000 10200



Ctrl+H
Find what: <audGrainData>\s+<startSample>(.+?)</startSample>\s+<pitch>(.+?)</pitch>\s+</audGrainData>\s*
Replace with: $1 $2 10000 10200\n you can use \r\n for Windows EOL
TICK Match case
TICK Wrap around
Search Mode Regular expression
UNTICK . matches newline
Replace all

Explanation:
<audGrainData>          # literally
\s+                     # 1 or more spaces, including linebreak
<startSample>           # literally
(.+?)                   # group 1, 1 or more any character
</startSample>          # literally
\s+                     # 1 or more spaces, including linebreak
<pitch>                 # literally
(.+?)                   # group 2, 1 or more any character
</pitch>                # literally
\s+                     # 1 or more spaces, including linebreak
</audGrainData>         # literally
\s*                     # 0 or more spaces, including linebreak

Screenshot (before):

Screenshot (after):

